# Backup Restore Data include Application

Tags: android

I will make android application with backup-restore data from google drive. Can anyone help me? Please...
If not from google drive, I also want from SDcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a load of documentation that is worth going through here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro

Also github link:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/

Remember that you need to authorise your app in the google developer console - you can do this with a debug key, which needs to be changed to the release key when the app is published. The documentation tells you all about it in the Authorize Requests section.

Comment: Thanks Mark Keen, if I want backup to sdcard, can you give source code?

Comment: If you get stuck ask another question with your code included stating what is happening/not happening - if you give it a good try then people will be willing to help.  This isn't a copy/paste forum :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Thanks ;)